# How to dynamically detect server's IP address (without custom DNS server)

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, networking, dns

I have a client application that I install in my customer's offices. It's a hybird application, which means that some of our customers require us to **install it inside their own network, without internet access**. There are also some customers, that use our *cloud* solution (**we also have version of an application in cloud - Azure**). Our server is ASP.NET application and client applications vary by platform - we have web apps, Windows desktop apps, as well as Android apps.

**So the problem is, that because of this heterogenous nature of the application, we need to rebuild our applications for each customer with different IP address of a server we have in their network. Apart from that we would also like to be able to use the same app for our "cloud" server, which can be reached also by static IP address or DNS name.**

What my constraints are:

1. Usually I don't have access to the internet from inside those networks
2. IP Address of the server depends on customers' network, it varies among customers
3. I cannot create one application with one IP or DNS address of my server, because server IP depends on my customers
4. I don't have DNS server, my customerss are very small companies that usually also don't have DNS server, only home-grade routers, nor do I want to setup my private DNS servers inside those networks, because I don't have access to customers' routers.
5. Usually I don't have access to customers' routers

How we do this today:

We rebuild the application and change IP for each customer every time we need to do install/update

How can I avoid those problems? What are the usual ways the industry solves this?

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: `IP Address of the server depends on client's architecture`. Hard to believe. How can a client influence the ip of a server?

Comment: `Thank you in advance for help.`. Why in advance? There are better moments.

Comment: client/customer runs their own routers, thay assign one static IP address for our server in their own network, usually we cannot change it

Comment: If the clients assign the ip for the server then what is the need to detect that same ip dynamically?

Comment: the point is that for each customer we need to rebuild the app for different IP address, I want to avoid that, have one app for every client/customer

Comment: could you explain why -1?

Comment: I really dont understand your probkem. Of course the server will have a different ip address at different customers. But that is no reason to hard code ip addresses.

Comment: how can you not hardcode IP address in Android application then?

Comment: There are several solutions. The simplest is to just let the user of the client app type in the ip of the server and then save that info.

Comment: That's what we do today, but it's far from perfect. I am looking for generic solution using (for example) TCP/IP network stack that is industry-standard for such problems, like broadcasting IP or something like that

Comment: Yes those things are possible too.

Comment: `IP Address of the server depends on client's network, it varies among clients`. Confusing sentence as there are servers and clients and you use the word client for customer too. 'Clients assigning an ip for the server' my god.. You ment customers.

Comment: It looks as if the only simple problem you have is 'how will the client application know the ip address of the server'. Well there are so many solutions for that! And hardcoding is no solution.

Comment: then please elaborate in a post about those solutions if you are interested in helping

Comment: This infers that you hard code the IP address into the client applications so they can connect to their server ?

Comment: The standard industry solution _is_ DNS. Tell your customers that when they assign an IP address to the server, they need to create a DNS entry for it in their DNS server.

Comment: what if my customers don't even have DNS servers, only home-grade routers that I don't have access to? Is there another way?

Comment: Most consumer-grade routers allow DNS entries. Hardcoded IP addresses are a rookie move. If you hardcode IP addresses, you cannot possibly be IPv6 ready. My company has followed the trend, and, like Apple, we require or vendors (hardware and software) to be able to run on an IPv6 network. Almost all the vendors claim IPv6 compatibility, until we get the product in the lab. Many vendors simply are not IPv6 ready. Some, like you, hardcode IP addresses, others simply have not even tested for IPv6. We tell them to come back when they are IPv6 ready, but we will probably have a solution by then.

Comment: As said before - use DNS. On startup try to resolve server name using default machine configuration. If that fails - try public dns (like Google). If that fails it means machine has no DNS and no internet. In that case adminstrator should write mapping to etc/hosts file on that machine OR you should ask user for server address to type manually and save that to hosts youself.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! After having read your comments, I think I know how to tackle the problem now ;)